# delegate works in xcode 5 but not in xcode 6

Tags: delegates, sprite-kit, skscene

```
@property (unsafe_unretained,nonatomic) id<SceneDelegate> delegate;
```

it works fine on xcode 5, but it gives me this error on xcode 6.1

```
Error: Property type 'id<SceneDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<SKSceneDelegate>' inherited from 'SKScene'
```

what's that mean?

Addition:

beginning of scene.h

```
@protocol SceneDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) eventStart;

@end

@interface Scene : SKScene<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (unsafe_unretained,nonatomic) id<SceneDelegate> delegate;
```

viewController.h

```
#import "Scene.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SceneDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

viewController.m

```
scene.delegate = self;
```

That's all the lines contain SceneDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means [SKScene already has a property of the same name](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/delegate): `delegate`

You are trying to redeclare that property but with a different protocol: `SceneDelegate` instead of `SKSceneDelegate`.

So either you wanted to use the delegate property, in that case you needn't declare that property, just assign your SKSceneDelegate object to the `delegate` property. For example:

```
self.delegate = mySceneDelegateObject;
```

Otherwise use a different name instead of `delegate` if `SceneDelegate` is an actual protocol you created (and consider renaming the protocol because it's easily confused with `SKSceneDelegate`).

Comment: Sorry @LearnCocos2D, I cannot get your advice work.  I have posted all the lines contain "SceneDelegate".

Comment: Your `Scene` class inherits from `SKScene`. SKScene already has a property named `delegate` of type `id<SKSceneDelegate>`. You try to redefine it as type `id<SceneDelegate>`. They are different types, and different delegates. Just use a different name other than `delegate` for your delegate property - for instance `mySceneDelegate`.

Comment: Great! Finally get it works now, changing like this: `@property (unsafe_unretained,nonatomic) id<SceneDelegate> mydelegate;`, and rename `self.delegate` to `self.mydelegate` in all codes. Thanks. BTW: still don't know why it works in xcode5?